# VS Code debugger not running: Attribute 'program' does not exist

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

VS Code's debugger has suddenly stopped working, after months of use. I tried to use it on a file, linkedListIntersection.js, and received the following error:

```
Attribute 'program' does not exist ('/path/to/linkedListIntersection.js').
```

My launch.json file is

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/linkedListIntersection.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answers on [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376884/attribute-program-does-not-exist-for-basic-node-js-project) questions center on correcting the file specified, but I only have one file.

Additionally, I get the error above whenever I try to start a debugging session on any file. Oddly, the error always refers to `linkedListIntersection.js`, even when I try to initiate debugging while in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by deleting the `linkedListIntersection.js` `launch.json` file.

Answer (score 5):

Just delete `launch.json` file from `.vscode`.It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions stated here, sadly none worked.
What worked eventually was deleting VSCode, including all of the extensions and reinstalling it.